# SHOW TABLES encountered Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: c#, mysql

In code, I drop a table and then create the table, and do the same in multi databases at one server, everything works ok. And then I query tables with the **SQL " SHOW TABLES "**, sometimes this sql throw exception: `Fatal error encountered during command execution`, sometimes it works ok. And I am sure this is not raised by **COMMAND TIMEOUT**. It should be other reasons.

here is the drop table and create table sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a`
SELECT 
  id,
  IF (mapping.name IS NULL, ne.autoname, mapping.name) AS autoname FROM b ne
LEFT JOIN test.a_mapping mapping ON ne.autoName = mapping.autoname;
ALTER TABLE `a` ADD INDEX `id_idx` (`id`); 
DELETE FROM `a` WHERE id = 1000000; 
INSERT INTO `a`(id, autoname) VALUES(1000000, @count);
```

here is the show tables codes:

```
  MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;
    try{            
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(MySqlUtils.SQL_GET_TABLES, connection);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = BaseOptimonConfig.Instance.CommandTimeout;
        dataReader = MySqlUtils.ExecuteReader(cmd); // just add try catch in this method.
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            if (MySqlUtils.GetSqlString(dataReader, 0).ToLower().Equals(tableName))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        MySqlUtils.CloseSqlReader(dataReader);
    }
```

Comment: show us the code and query

Comment: on which line you are getting error

Comment: dataReader = MySqlUtils.ExecuteReader(cmd);

Comment: try
            {
                return command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (MySqlException myEx)
            {
            }

Comment: just try catch command.ExecuteReader(); in the method.

Comment: @user1611748 Could you try this query  `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` instead of `show tables` and let us know the result?

Comment: @Namphibian, What is the difference between them?

Comment: It seems another sql which equal in the functionality walkaround the issue.